# Why correlation calculated by 'cor' function in R differs from cosine of angle between vectors

Tags: r, correlation, dot-product

I'm trying to demonstrate that the cosine of the angle between vectors is the same as the correlation coefficient between them.  However, the *cor* function in R and the value I get from the dot product definition of the cosine of the angle are different.

```
data("anscombe")


x <- matrix(anscombe$x1)
y <- matrix(anscombe$y1)

cor(x,y)

(t(x)%*%y) / ((norm(x, type = 'f') * norm(y, type = 'f')))
```

If you can point to any mistake in my code or any thoughts on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to center the vectors for the cosine of the angle between vectors to achieve the same answer. The Pearson correlation is cosine similarity between *centered* vectors so if you center the vectors and do the cosine similarity it produces the same answer.

```
data("anscombe")


x <- matrix(anscombe$x1)
y <- matrix(anscombe$y1)
z <- x - mean(x)
aa <- y - mean(y)

cor(x,y)


(t(z)%*%aa) / ((norm(z, type = 'f') * norm(aa, type = 'f')))
```